# How to test if a web site returns cookie using java?

Tags: java, cookies, web

Hi I'm trying to test whether a site returns a cookie or not. I'm very new to Java.

I Have opened the connection using :

```
conn = "https://mysite.com/".toURL().openConnection()
```

Having opened the connection, how to test whether the site `mysite` returns the cookie or not?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start with, I'd suggest using a higher level API than `URLConnection`. There are various HTTP libraries around. Some of them would even work out all the cookies for you - but even if they don't... you just need to check for the `Set-Cookie` header in the response. (If you *do* want to stick with `URLConnection`, that gives you the headers too... I'm just generally wary of it being a pain compared with other HTTP libraries.)

`Set-Cookie` is used by the server to send cookies to the client; the `Cookie` header is used by the client to send cookies back to the server. See [RFC 2965](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2965.txt) and [RFC 6265](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6265.txt) for more information.